# How do I target an input when 5 characters have been entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is take an input for a zipcode and in jQuery if input#zip has 5 characters then function. Also same for a list box when the user chooses one of the choices, might be simpler?

Comment: You can be  little more explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#zip-input').keyup(function(){ 
    if($(this).val().length == 5) {
    //do your stuff here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For your zip scenario:

```
$("#zip").keypress(function() {
  if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length == 5) {
    someFunction($(this).val());
  }
});
```

For your listbox scenario:

```
$("#listbox").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    someFunction($(this).val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a `keyup` event handler for instance.

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function(){
   if($(this).val().length >= 5){
      alert('5 characters');
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the .change(). Each time change is fired get the length of the input and, if its 5 or more, run your code.